# Parsing formatted JSON with Python

Tags: python, json, parsing, formatting

I want to parse JSON. Its ok if I write JSON in one line

```
json_input = '{ "rate_of_climbing": 18.4, "speed_factor": 520}'
```

But if I have JSON formated then parser does not work:

```
json_input = '{ 
    "rate_of_climbing": 18.4, 
    "speed_factor": 520
}'
```

How can I get JSON to read for formatted string?

My full code:

```
import json
json_input = '{ 
    "rate_of_climbing": 18.4, 
    "speed_factor": 520
}'

try:
    decoded = json.loads(json_input)

    print json.dumps(decoded, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
    print "JSON parsing example: ", decoded['rate_of_climbing']
    print "Complex JSON parsing example: ", decoded['speed_factor']

except (ValueError, KeyError, TypeError):
    print "JSON format error"
```

Comment: The way you define the **Python** string doesn't work. The `json` module works just fine...

Comment: Presumably you are getting a `SyntaxError` here; if you are getting a **different** error, can you remove the `try` and `except` lines (unindent the rest) and show us the error you are getting? Include the sample input that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `'''triple-quoted string literals'''` (or `"""triple-quoted string literals"""`) if the string contains newlines.

```
json_input = '''{ 
    "rate_of_climbing": 18.4, 
    "speed_factor": 520
}'''
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can store these json data info a file;
then read all:

```
json_data = ''.join([line.strip() for line in open('path to json file')])
```

then,

```
_data = json.loads(json_data) 
json.dumps(_data)
```

Comment: Thanks, maybe I will use your suggestion later!